# Seagate Central NAS Drive corrupted / Not Mounting Shares

Tags: linux, mount, nas, storage

Good Morning,

I have a Seagate Central NAS Drive that has been running fine for years but has suddenly stopped working correctly. It will power up and is available on the network but is showing no files on the share where there were.

The web interface was still available however not reporting correctly free space etc. And trying to add a new user it messed up the user xml so I am no longer able to log into the web interface.

I assumed this was a hard drive failure however after removing this and connecting it directly into the PC I can see that all the files are there and available.

I have re-assembled the device and did a reset to see if that would help but there is definitely something up with the firmware/linux as I can't log in to that interface or change anything. However, I can SFTP onto it and see the Linux files and I can SSH onto it with the admin user.

My Linux skills are basic and rusty so I wondered if anyone had any suggestions so I can get it back to a basic level of functionality and not have to take the drive out and bin the enclosure. I should be able to reset the root password to have full access to everything but I'm not going Hell for Leather on it without suggestions first.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Apparently, others have had similar issues, perhaps due to damage to an IC: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/my-seagate-central-nas-great-until-more-mirko-torrez-contreras . Perhaps the Seagate NAS OS Rescue & Repair might work, if applicable and just an OS glitch: https://www.seagate.com/manuals/network-storage/business-storage-nas-os-4/nas-os-rescue-and-repair/